# Sublime text editor shows unregistered. Any suggestions?

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

I have installed sublime text editor and mavensmate on it. What i found on the title bar is "unregistered". Do i need to purchase a license or am i missing something? Please advice.

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**From the Sublime Text Site**

> Sublime Text may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a
>   license must be purchased for continued use.
>
> Licenses are per-user, rather than per-machine, so you can enjoy
>   Sublime Text on as many computers and operating systems as you wish
>   with your license.

**You can purchase a license here**

http://www.sublimetext.com/buy

Comment: Thanks @sfdc_ninja. Why cant salesforce make it as a free tool like the force.com ide plugin on eclipse? I am feeling this is a big constraint as the evaluation version may miss some good features.

Comment: Mavens mate is an open source plugin for Sublime text.  Sublime text is a tool used for many other languages and uses other than force.com work.  Mavens Mate is not created by or maintained by Sublime Text, its just a plugin.

Comment: Understood. So i can use Mavensmate forever unless Sublime text asks for the license key. Is that right? Would Mavensmate work without sublime text?

Comment: Correct.  I dont know if Sublime will ever force you to enter a key or not, but the license is very reasonably priced, so I tend to recommend purchasing, if nothing else to help keep the product supported and active.  MavensMate is a plugin for Sublime text, unless they come up with a plugin for another code editor, you would need sublime text to use MavensMate

Comment: MavensMate also works with [ATOM](https://atom.io/) that is a free editor.